# Team Fortress 2 wont start after installing custom GUI and content?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, mods

I have recently experienced some problems with starting Team Fortress 2.

Yesterday I installed a few sprites, skins, adn GUI's, but ever since I did that the game says

> Failed to Start Game (Missing Executable).

I downloaded the mods from gamebanana.com.

Can someone please help? I can't play TF2 anymore, I already tried what the Steam Support site says.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if we should support this stuff here. We don't allow mine craft mods so why this?

Comment: @Judge2020 - because this doesn't have close to the amount of problems that Modded Minecraft Tech support has. This is a reproducible, common problem with a well defined debugging process and solution, based on a game that only has one current version and a smaller mod space. We don't ban all animals if it's only dogs that are causing problems

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall Team Fortress 2.

- Uninstall by right-clicking Team Fortress 2 in your Steam library, and selecting `Delete Local Content`
- Then, install it again as you normally would.

Comment: This is a bit extreme. Running a 'Verify Integrity' will download missing files, OP should try that first.

Comment: @Robotnik yes, but OP modded his install, so who knows what may have been messed up. Verify may miss some files

Comment: Thanks for the help guys,I will try to do what each one of you answered :)

Comment: @zwork - It also redownloads any 'corrupted' files, i.e. Ones that differ from the copy on the Steam servers, effectively resetting any bad changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try verifying your game cache to download any missing files:

1. Go to your Steam library
2. Right click on Team Fortress 2
3. Click Properties
4. Click Local Files
5. Click "Verify Integrity of game cache"

A progress bar will then appear and it will be done after a few minutes. Then try relaunching the game. If it still doesn't work, do as @zwork says and reinstall.

Comment: Guys but how can I still play Team Fortress 2 with the mods and the game not being corrupted in any way at the same time?

Comment: You would reinstall the game, and then re-mod it.

Comment: @PacTheGamer It depends on the mods you're using. Chances are you messed up somewhere along the line, if you're having trouble with it after you've fixed this problem you can always ask another question about trying to make your mods work

Comment: Thanks guys,but I reinstalled with the atleast one mod along but I just can't use the mod.